# Documentation or example in Android for live streaming through RTMP

Tags: android, rtmp, live-streaming

I am planning to make an app for video live streaming ,and I searched a lot for that, if any example for live streaming using rtsp, but no luck for rtmp.
I have requirement using RTMP protocol for streaming. There is quite good player for rtmp but didn't found any example  streaming using rtmp

Comment: Is it possible for you to build an AIR app?

Comment: i m not aware for this, if you provide some guide then surely i will build AIR

Comment: Here is an article about that (with a free IDE) : http://kaliko.com/blog/create-android-app-with-flash/ . Then you can inspire yourself with this sample of publisher : https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/tree/master/VideoPublisher

Comment: Thanx thomas  i will try with this.